# Wordpress always thinks DB_HOST is localhost

Tags: database, wordpress, amazon-rds

I've tried to install Wordpress on my website server, which seems to go fine until I get a standard database connection error.

> This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at `localhost`. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

I'm using an AWS RDS endpoint for the DB_HOST in the configuration, but the odd thing is that the code seems to always think that my DB_HOST is `localhost` regardless of what I put into `wp-config.php`. If you look into the source code for the database, it checks the DB_HOST when passing the error above, so it is definitely checking what the DB_HOST value is.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though wp-config.php is not cached, something like that was happening. Once I rebooted my server, it finally stopped recognizing localhost as the database location.